# Proof by induction for java algorithm

Tags: algorithms, induction, recursive-algorithms, programming, analysis-of-algorithms

```
double expRecursive(double x, int n) {
    if (n <= 4) {
        return expIterativ(x, n);
    }

    return expRecursive(x, n/2) *
           expRecursive(x, (n + 1)/2); }
```

Base Case: I checked that it works.

Inductive assumption: for n=p is:
expRecursive($x,\frac{p}2$)×expRecursive($x,\frac {p+1}2)=x^p$

The proof, now I will show that it works for n=p+1:

expRecursive($x,\frac{p+1}2$)×expRecursive($x,\frac {p+2}2)= x^\frac{p+1}2 *  x^\frac{p+2}2$

But obviously this doesn't equal to $x^{p+1}$, can someone help?

Comment: Do `n/2` and `(n + 1)/2` in your program round down to the nearest integer?

Comment: Input $n$ as a float. This should solve the issue. If you want an **int** output then simply cast the function to **int** upon assigning it. Since, your output is an int in the form of a float it should not matter about the rounding ($x^{p+1}$ is an integer after all)

Answer (score 3):

This is a little subtle, and it involves the semantics of the `/` operator, which rounds down.

If $n$ is even, then `n / 2` evaluates to $\frac{n}{2}$, as does `(n + 1)/2`. So in this case, we use the strong inductive hypothesis to see that we are computing $(x^{\frac{n}{2}})^2 = x^n$.

Similarly, if $n$ is odd, then `n / 2` evaluates to $\frac{n - 1}{2}$, while `(n + 1)/2` evaluates to $\frac{n + 1}{2}$. So in this case, we use the strong inductive hypothesis to show we are computing $x^{\frac{n - 1}{2}} x^{\frac{n + 1}{2}} = x^n$, as required.